# case-of with Random.Generate Int

Tags: elm

I am new with elm. Elm version is 0.19. I am trying to use Ranndom.int to select ship type, but don't know how to do it.
What should I do with the function numToShip? Change the type?

Here is my code ...

```
type ShipType
    = Battleship
    | Cruiser   
    | Destroyer 
    | Submarine 

numToShip : Int -> ShipType
numToShip num =
   case num of
     0 -> Destroyer
     1 -> Battleship
     2 -> Cruiser
     _ -> Submarine

shipName : ShipType -> String
shipName shipType =
  case shipType of
    Destroyer ->
        "Destroyer"
    Battleship ->
        "Battleship"
    Cruiser ->
        "Cruiser"
    Submarine ->
        "Submarine"

randomShip : String
randomShip =
  shipName (numToShip (Random.int 0 3) )
```

error message is:

```
The 1st pattern in this `case` causing a mismatch:

 146|   case num of

 147|>    0 -> Destroyer 

 148|     1 -> Battleship

 149|     2 -> Cruiser

 150|     _ -> Submarine

The first pattern is trying to match integers:
    Int

But the expression between `case` and `of` is:
    Random.Generator Int
```

These can never match! Is the pattern the problem? Or is it the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Random.int`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/random/latest/Random#int) does not return an `Int`, but a [`Generator Int`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/random/latest/Random#Generator).  You'll then call [`Random.generate`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/random/latest/Random#generate) to turn that `Generator` into a `Cmd`, which will then call your `update` function with the generated value.

One of the characteristics of Elm is that all functions are *pure*, meaning that the same inputs always result in the same outputs.  Since you're asking for a different value each time you call the function, you need to hand that command off to the runtime, which can handle the impurity of the request (which is the same thing that happens when you want to communicate with the outside world via HTTP or JavaScript).  See [the `Random` example in the Elm Guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/effects/random.html) for more details.

Alternatively, you can get a value immediately from the `Generator` if you are willing to supply a seed used to calculate the random value.  You can use [`Random.step`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/random/latest/Random#step), which takes a `Generator` and a [`Seed`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/random/latest/Random#Seed), and produces a value *and* the next seed, which you can feed back into `step` if you need multiple values.  You'll probably only want to do this if it's useful to be able to "replay" your random values, as it's kind of a pain to keep the `Seed` around.  Otherwise, just stick with using `generate` to create a `Cmd`.